# What is the difference between chars and strings?

Tags: c, string, char, cs50

I am working on cs50 coding exercise but I don't get strings and chars. I have problems with them cause I can't understand what they are. I don't know the difference between chars and strings cause they seem the same to me. My code is:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
char c=A;
printf("%c", c);
string a = A;
printf("%s", a);
}
```

but it prints AA without changes whether it is a char or string.
If I do this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
char c=A;
printf("%c", c);
char a = A;
printf("%c", a);
}
```

it still prints AA. Even if I do this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
string c=A;
printf("%s", c);
string a = A;
printf("%s", a);
}
```

It STILL prints AA, even if I swap from chars to strings. I don't see a difference at all! Please help me understand.
I change from chars to strings but the result doesn't change. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: Its similar to digits vs numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `char` represents a single character. A string is a series of characters.

Comment: Thanks I understand now : )

Comment: The character sequence must also be terminated by a 0 byte to be a valid C string.

Comment: A string could also be zero characters

Comment: @user253751: a string always has at least the null character, so can't really be zero characters

Comment: @prng Depends on whether you count the null character as part of the string. Is the string "hello world" or is it "hello world\0"? I think most people would agree it's the former.

Comment: I tend to go by the C Standard :) --- `""` is a string with one character: the null character

Answer (score 0):

string is Alias of String in which we can store collection of Char Called Word like
string name = "mukesh"; but in char we can store single character only like

char ch='b';

Answer (score 0):

A string is an array of chars.

A `char` is just one character or letter in english.

Like examples of chars are 'A', 'B', 'w', '3', '\n' etc.

In C/C++, a `char` takes 1 byte of space and is within single quotes.

Special characters like `'\n'`, `'\0'` are also chars.

They take 1 byte of storage and can be represented as an integer also. Search ASCII on google to understand the integer relation.

`string` is a collection of chars.

Examples are "John", "Hello", "What is an Apple?".

The chars inside string "John" are `J`,`o`,`h`,`n`,`\0`. The length of the string is 5. A string always terminates with a `\0` char.

strings are inside double quotes in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible common-use definitions of *string* (the C standard defines "*A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.*", see [C11 7.1.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1))

a) an array of `char` values of which the last one has value `0`, eg

```
(char[4]){'b', 'a', 'r', '\0'}  // a) string
```

b) an array of `char` values that contains a `'\0'`, eg

```
(char[7]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0', 'x', 'y', 'z'} // not an a) string; b) string
```

this last string can "grow" because the underlying array has enough space

c) a pointer to one of the above or to somewhere in the middle of such an array, eg

```
char array[10] = "foo\0bar\0X"; // not an a) string
char *p = &arr[4];              // not an a) string, not a b) string
```

This last `array` is not a string for definition a), it is a string for definition 2) string; `p` points to the `'b'`: that pointer is a string by definition c).

Always make sure you know what kind of string you're discussing!!

Of these definitions, c) is the one farthest from the C Standard definition.